# Trigger for disabling edit and delete record

Tags: apex, trigger

I come to the problem of restricting edit and delete on page view in certain conditions.
I have a related list paced in Object Case, showing records from custom object Transactions__c.

When Case have a status of '7', user shouldnt be able to delte or edit that record over this links.

It should be done by apex trigger but i didnt find any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a trigger on `Transactions__c`, it should be `before update` and `before delete`.

In the trigger, check the case status via SOQL query and if those status is `7` then show the error message.

Refer [Get Started with Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_intro)